# How to setup HTTPS with jetty embedded 8.1.16.v20140903

Tags: java, ssl, https, embedded-jetty

I am using one of the example jetty embedded projects from [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.16.v20140903/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java)

I added a SelectChannelConnect, SslSelectChannelConnect and SslSocketConnector as shown in the link above.
Here is a snippet from my code:

```
// Create the server
Server server = new Server();

SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(80);
connector.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
connector.setConfidentialPort(8443);
connector.setStatsOn(false);
connector.setAcceptors(4);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[]
                       { connector });

SslSelectChannelConnector ssl_connector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
ssl_connector.setPort(443);
SslContextFactory cf = ssl_connector.getSslContextFactory();
cf.setKeyStorePath("/path/to/keystore");
cf.setKeyStorePassword("password");
cf.setKeyManagerPassword("password");
cf.setTrustStore("/path/to/keystore");
cf.setTrustStorePassword("password");
cf.setExcludeCipherSuites(
  "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
  "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
  "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
  "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
  "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
  "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
  "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");
ssl_connector.setStatsOn(false);
server.addConnector(ssl_connector);
ssl_connector.open();

SslSocketConnector ssl2_connector = new SslSocketConnector(cf);
ssl2_connector.setPort(443);
ssl2_connector.setStatsOn(false);
server.addConnector(ssl2_connector);
ssl2_connector.open();

server.start()
```

HTTP works fine but I am not able to get it to work on HTTPS. It gives me an initial warning in the browser about untrusted certificate blah blah. I added an exception but then it displays this message: "This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner." on IE. My settings on IE are alright with TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 checked and SSL 3.0 unchecked.

Am I missing something? I believe I followed everything from the example project.

Also I generated the keystore and built the project from jdk SE 6u45. I do not think there are any issues the keystore file as it works perfectly in another application.

Comment: With SSL/TLS at the server side, you need to keep your JVM up to date.  The configuration you are using was valid back in 2014, and now, in the year 2021, that same configuration is actually vulnerable and no longer supported by most browsers.

Comment: Jetty 8.x was set to EOL (End of Life) back in the year 2014.  Consider upgrading - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Unfortunately, I am not at a luxury to upgrade jetty or java. Also the application I will be using this in will be run locally. Can I get it to work with an older version browser?

Comment: you would need an exceedingly old browser, something released around 2013-2014 time frame should do.

Comment: Note that if you downgrade your browser, only your browser will be able to access that website, no other user, or firewall, or load balancer, or http client, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browser no longer support SSLv3, TLS/1.0 and TLS/1.1.

*Chrome Announcement*
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/chrome-84-deps-rems

*Firefox Announcement*
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/10/15/removing-old-versions-of-tls/

*Apple Safari Announcement*
https://webkit.org/blog/8462/deprecation-of-legacy-tls-1-0-and-1-1-versions/

*Microsoft Announcement*
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/10/15/modernizing-tls-edge-ie11/#OkGpBsuyj6XwhUEQ.97

You should be using TLS/1.2 or better (eg: TLS/1.3)

Java 6u45 does not support TLS/1.2, you have to upgrade your JVM at a minimum.
You need to be on Java 7u95 or newer for decent TLS/1.2 support.
For TLS/1.3 support you need to be on Java 8u262 or newer.

Pay attention to JVM expiration dates.
This is important for long term success with SSL/TLS, as the expiration exist because of various databases and configurations within the JVM need to be kept up to date for SSL/TLS to function reliably with the general internet.

Finally, get rid of the entire `setExcludeCipherSuites` you have, as every one of those cipher suites are excluded by the JVM itself now (see security.properties on a modern JVM)